# Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == cuCtxSetCurrent

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

- When I run hparams Dashboard following (1), the 1rst trial runs fine, but for the 2d one I have this error message (2) then the slurm job stop.
- I'm using: keras with tensorflow_GPU; use_multiprocessing = True (in 'model.fit_generator'); python = 3.6.7; tensorFlow = 2.0.0; keras = 2.2.4-tf.
- It's strange because it happens only after the successful 1st trial.
- I tried to use 'K.clear_session()' but it did not help.

(1)

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams

(2)

--- Starting trial: run-0

!! ALL RUN FILE HERE !!

--- Starting trial: run-1

Epoch 1/2

F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:225] Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == cuCtxSetCurrent(cuda_context->context()) (0 vs. 3)

!! THEN NOTHING IS HAPPENING ANYMORE!!